# Package get stored in Temporary file

Tags: rstudio

when i install package in RStudio it gets stored in temporary folder and i cannot load it to the working space. Can anyone help me solve this problem.

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpFuUEEd/downloaded_packages’

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the Packages tab in the same panel that has the Plots and Help tab (ctrl-7 on windows) you can press Install at the top left, and then specify where the files get saved on the third input box "Install to Library:".

Hope that helps, but let me know if you need more specification.

Comment: yes..In the third input box also i have mentioned the R library path only, still i get the same thing

Comment: Can you specify a generalized version of the directory your're using. For example: mine would be: "C:/Users/userName/Documents/R/win-library/3.4". On non-Windows OS it should be different but that shouldn't be an challenge for diagnosing the issue.

Comment: /home/pavitra/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6[default]